# Proof $\{x \in l^{\infty} \space| \lim\limits_{i \to \infty}\space x_i = y \space$ exists and $y \ge 0 \}$ is closed set in $ l^{\infty} $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

Good afernoon, I wish you all a good Sunday!

I want to show that $M \subset l^{\infty} $ is a closed set without using "A set $A$ is closed if all cauchy series has it limit in $A$".

$$l^{\infty}:=  \text{Set of bounded sequences}$$

$$M :=\{x \in l^{\infty} \space| \space\space\space \lim\limits_{i \to \infty}\space x_i = y \space \text{exists} \space \text{and} \space y \ge 0 \}$$

Has anyone an Idea how to proof that?

Comment: Since $l^\infty$ is complete, the sentence "a set $A$ is closed if any Cauchy sequence in $A$ has a limit in $A$" is equivalent to "a set $A$ is closed if any sequence in $A$ convergent in $l^\infty$ has its limit in $A$". If using this definition of closedness is forbidden, what definition are you allowed to use?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz sorry for the late reply. The defintion of closedness is: "A subset $A$ is closed if the Complement of $A$ is open".

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz your defintion would still apply here but would not in topological spaces, as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only going to give you a partial answer. But first, I dislike the double use of $x$ as naming both the sequence and its limit (if it exists), so I'll depart from that notation.

The complement of $M$ consists of two kinds of sequences:

1. Sequences for which $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=c<0$, and
2. Sequences which have no limit.

For the first kind, you can show that no sequence in a ball of radius $|c|$ around $x$ belongs to $M$.

The second kind will have at least two limit points, say, $c_1$ and $c_2$. Now you can show that any sequence close enough to this one must diverge.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt notice the double use, I will fix it.
And yes, I did it the same way. Thank you!